# could not load mongodb module for rsyslog

Tags: mongodb, logging, configuration, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to configure rsyslog to directly log into MongoDB using the `ommongodb` module.

I added following code to the `rsyslog.conf` file:

```
module(load="ommongodb") 
action(type="ommongodb" server="<ip_addr>:" db="db_name"
    collection="collection_name" uid="user" pwd="pwd")
```

After restarting the rsyslog service, I got the following error:

```
could not load module 'ommongodb', 
errors: trying to load module /usr/lib64/rsyslog/ommongodb.so: /usr/lib64/
```

I followed the instructions provided in [this guide](https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-rsyslog-and-mongodb/), but haven't been able to get it running.

---

I am using a RHEL distribution. rsyslog version: [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2]

Comment: This seems very visible for being "hidden".

Comment: Is the module installed? You can check using `ls /usr/lib64/rsyslog/ommongodb.so`. If yes, check directory/file permissions.